# Why does adding border-top make left column move to middle column?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to create a list where all list-item have `border-bottom: 1px solid;` and separate it into 3 columns with `column-count:3`. So if i were to have 8 items it would display 3 items in the first column, 3 in second and 2 in the third.

Which is working fine, but the issue start when i want to add `border-top: 1px solid` on the first element.
Instead of display `"3,3,2"` its showing as `"2,3,3"`.

The reason I'm not using grid is because the number of items I wanna show can be variate.

I made an example with the same behaviour.

```css
.wrapper {
  column-count: 3;
}

.border-bottom {
  break-inside: avoid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper">
  <li class="border-bottom border-top">
    A
  </li>
  <li class="border-bottom">
    B
  </li>
   <li class="border-bottom">
    C
  </li>
   <li class="border-bottom">
    D
  </li>
   <li class="border-bottom">
    E
  </li>
   <li class="border-bottom">
    F
  </li>
   <li class="border-bottom">
    G
  </li>
     <li class="border-bottom">
    H
  </li>
</ul>
```

Same code without `Border-top:1px solid` on the first `<li>`

```css
.wrapper {
  column-count: 3;
}

.border-bottom {
  break-inside: avoid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper">
  <li class="border-bottom">
    A
  </li>
  <li class="border-bottom">
    B
  </li>
   <li class="border-bottom">
    C
  </li>
   <li class="border-bottom">
    D
  </li>
   <li class="border-bottom">
    E
  </li>
   <li class="border-bottom">
    F
  </li>
   <li class="border-bottom">
    G
  </li>
     <li class="border-bottom">
    H
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a 1px transparent border to make them all the same size.

Check the snippet:

```css
.wrapper {
  column-count: 3;
}

.border-bottom {
  break-inside: avoid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  border:1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper">
  <li class="border-bottom border-top">
    A
  </li>
  <li class="border-bottom">
    B
  </li>
   <li class="border-bottom">
    C
  </li>
   <li class="border-bottom">
    D
  </li>
   <li class="border-bottom">
    E
  </li>
   <li class="border-bottom">
    F
  </li>
   <li class="border-bottom">
    G
  </li>
     <li class="border-bottom">
    H
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How this problem was solved by border?!!!!!!

Comment: when you give an element a border you affect its size, so the browser sees that that element is bigger than others so it moves the last element in the column to next one.
Another way would be using outline as outlines does not affect the size, but this is the best way in your case.